# Should I always implicitly Dispose WCF Service Clients and Data Contexts?

Tags: c#, .net

VS 2010 Beta Code Analysis is advising me to always dispose WCF Service Clients and Data Contexts for LINQ to SQL.  Is this advisable?  I assume this will eventually happen regardless.  What are the pros/cons of doing so implicitly or not at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **anything** that is `IDisposable`, it is your job to ensure it gets cleaned up promptly, to close open resources etc (connections, etc). So in short, yes. Finalizers only happen when GC kicks in, which can be a long time - and doesn't allow for the best pooling use etc.

Note however that WCF has a history of dodgy `Dispose()` implementations, making *just* `using` a bit hit-n-miss (you can lose the actual exception). Of course, it is also recommended to use WCF via async methods, which again makes it hard to use `using`; you'll often need to keep a reference and call `Dispose()` explicitely in the IO callback.

---

Re your comments; a few examples:

- `SqlConnection`: if you leave this hanging around (open) you prevent it reusing the connection from a pool; you can ultimately saturate the available connections this way, breaking your app
- GDI: IIRC, VS2005 itself (or 2003?) had a bug where an undisposed GDI object; GDI objects don't take much **memory**, so it didn't trigger GC, but it ran out of available handles and broke (this is a common bug in user code too, but more famous in an IDE)
- fail to dispose something like a `FileStream`: you've blocked your file system
- fail to dispose a `TransactionScope` and you've caused db (etc) blocking

Comment: I understand the argument you're giving as the textbook reason, however textbox says Generics are faster than unboxing/boxing Objects and that's simply not the case by a longshot.  Do you have any performance or other negative side effects that can be shown by not doing this?